# Sql Server - detect a cell match

Tags: sql-server-2012

is it possible in sql server to detect if 2 cells are the same, for example

```
ID    | Quantity  |SerialNo | QuantityRemaining
1     |     1     |  1234   |         0
2     |    -1     |  1234   |         0
```

and then based on the Serial matching, ammend the overall quantity for that field to 0 in this case as ive typed above? or a more efficient way maybe? or is it  better to simply update the total quantity field within a view I have which calculates the total based upon a product code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx):

```
SELECT SerialNo,
 SUM(Quantiy) AS QuantityRemaining
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY SerialNo
ORDER BY SerialNo
```